# "Unsupported configuration attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]" when trying to configure Spring 4 / OAuth 2

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I recently upgraded to Spring SEcurity 4.2.2.RELEASE and now I'm having trouble with my OAuth2 configuration (using v 2.0.7.RELEASE).  I want to force URLs that look like '/context-path/api/**' to require an OAuth access token.  SO I have

```
<http pattern="/api/**"  
              create-session="never"
              entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
              access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
              xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
 <anonymous enabled="false" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/**"
                         access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
 <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
                         before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
 <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
```

HOwever, after upgrading to Spring SEcurity 4, I'm getting this error ...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]
```

WHat's the right way to indicate that the user must have fully authenticated in order to access my resource?

Comment: I believe you are running into this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/625

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in Spring Security 4.x XML configuration uses expressions by default and IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY is not the expression syntax. Either disable expressions using 
`use-expressions="false"` in your `<http>` tag or replace IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY with `fullyAuthenticated`.

Comment: this is @Rob Winch's answer, and this is the correct one!